# Lock Screen / Screen Saver

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I do a lot of work in front of my computer (whether on or off) while listening to music.  I have a bunch of awesome high-resolution desktop backgrounds that I'd like to be able to look at but they're only really available in the form I'm thinking of as a screensaver.  It would be awesome if I could simultaneously lock my screen and start my screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

Check out & install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's super easy to use, and you can add the file to your startup folder so the script will launch everytime your computer starts. The code below remaps the Windows + L key to launch the screensaver. Then when mouse movement or keyboard input is detected, it'll lock your PC preventing unwanted access.

Add the below to a new text file, and name it something useful (like `screenlock.ahk`). Then just run the `.ahk` file and press Win + L.

```
#l::
    RunWait, "C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr" /s
    Run, rundll32 user32.dll`,LockWorkStation
return
```

Only need to replace the path to the screensaver file.

Comment: Doesn't quite work.  I still get the computer lock and the screensaver doesn't run (that I can see).

Comment: It appears the original windows lock action takes precedence over the screensaver starting and cancels it bringing me to the lock screen.

Comment: @theStandard Strange! It worked for me with the example above using bubbles.scr. It shows the screensaver first, then when I had keyboard/mouse input, it cancelled screensaver and locked the screen. AutoHotKey is powerful stuff, I'm sure there's a small tweak you can make to it to make it work.

Comment: I tried it with bubbles originally too.